# How to access My.Resources in .aspx?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, .net-4.0

I have a string resource I can access in my code behind like so:

```
My.Resources.SomeStringResource
```

But if I try to access it in the .aspx like this:

```
<a href="http://someurl.com"><%=My.Resources.SomeStringResource %></a>
```

It does not compile.  It seems `My.Computer`, `My.Log`, `My.Request` and some others are available but not `My.Resources`.

Is what I am trying to do possible?

Comment: What project type is this... Website? Web Application?

Comment: My answer should show you, you may need to adjust the root namespace according to your projects namespace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the resource access modifier to "Public" in the *.RESX file:

[image]

and then access in the code-front like so:

```
<%= WebApplication1.My.Resources.Resource1.String2%>
```

Comment: Thank you, both this and Don J's answer worked, I selected this as the answer as I wouldn't have to change all the references to My.Resources in my code behinds

Answer (score 3):

Resource files in ASP.NET Web Applications are created and used in a different manner (specially when you want to utilize them in the markup, which is what you're after)

The reason you cannot access My.Resources from the markup is because the Markup file gets compiled into a separate class by the ASP.NET framework into a separate assembly, and that assembly doesn't have acces to My.Resource (flagged as "Friend" access only).

So for ASP.NET application you would have to create you resource file in the App_GlobalResources (if using a shared resource) and then use then in the following manner:

Assume the name of the resource file is "GLobalResources" in the App_GlobalResources directory.

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:GlobalResources, MyName %>" />
```

For further information please have a look at the following page:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227427.aspx

Comment: I added an alternate solution, which was to change the access modifier to "Public" so you can use them anywhere.

Comment: Thank you, your solution did work, I selected laylarenee's as the best answer as I wouldn't have to change my code behind.  Would upvote you if I had the rep.